# How to elegantly iterate through the nodes of a boost R-tree while it's being modified?

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree

I'm using a boost R-tree (boost version 1.65.1 and C++ 17) to iterate over some 2D points. What I want to do is to perform neighbour searches for each node (so 'detect' neighbouring nodes), do some stuff with the results, and afterwards remove all query result nodes from the r-tree. Then I want to iterate over the remaining nodes and repeat until I reached the end.

The problem now is that modifying the r-tree this way not only may but in my case *does* invalidate the iterator. This basically results in a never ending for-loop among other problems.

Right now I don't see an other way to solve this than to reset the iterator to `begin()`.

So my question is:

**Is there a more elegant way to do this?**

The basic code snippet using an r-tree which stores pairs of 2D-points and some number:

```
for (auto it = someRTree.begin(); it != someRTree.end(); ++it) {
    std::vector<std::pair<point, size_t>> results;
    // Creating a query box around the current node
    bgm::box<point> queryBox(point(bg::get<0>(it->first) - someConst,
                                   bg::get<1>(it->first) - someConst),
                             point(bg::get<0>(it->first) + someConst,
                                   bg::get<1>(it->first) + someConst));
    someRTree.query(bgi::intersects(queryBox), std::back_inserter(results));

    // do something with the results
    // ...

    someRTree.remove(results); // <- This here will invalidate the iterator.
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any solution to this. Modifying an R-Tree not only means that occasionally nodes need to be merged, but that occasionally the tree is rebalanced, i.e. remaining entries are moved around, i.e. essentially reordered. Even if an iterator is valid after an erase(), reordering means that you would encounter some elements multiple times (moved ahead of the iterator) or never at all (moved to the part that the iterator already traversed). If you need stable iterators, you may need a different data structure. Are you required to use an R-Tree?

Comment: I see. Makes sense. I don't necessarily need an R-tree. But I need to be able to perform spatial queries on hundreds of thousands of 2D point-structures. R-tree seems to be a good option for this purpose.

Comment: You could also use a [PH-tree](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree-cpp) (disclaimer: self advertisement). All coordinates are Morton-ordered, so insert/erase will never change the order. Query performance is probably somewhat slower than Boost R-Tree, but `erase()` should be faster (at least for 3D, I rarely use it with 2D). After `erase()` you can use `lower_bound()` to find the next entry after. Depending on your use case you probably want to use the multimap variant.
Note that `lower_bound()` is only available in the main branch, it didn't make it into the last release.

Answer (score 0):

Since the query results are going to be removed from the r-tree anyway, I found a solution, which is a little bit simpler. Basically the for loop is transformed into a while loop and the iterator is set at the beginning of each loop iteration to the beginning of the r-tree. This also makes case handling unnecessary which might otherwise be necessary when using a for loop.

```
while (!someRTree.empty()) {
    auto it = someRTree.begin(); // Set iterator at beginning of while loop.

    std::vector<std::pair<point, size_t>> results;
    // Creating a query box around the current node
    bgm::box<point> queryBox(point(bg::get<0>(it->first) - someConst,
                                   bg::get<1>(it->first) - someConst),
                             point(bg::get<0>(it->first) + someConst,
                                   bg::get<1>(it->first) + someConst));
    someRTree.query(bgi::intersects(queryBox), std::back_inserter(results));

    // do something with the results
    // ...

    someRTree.remove(results); // <- Iterator will still be invalidated, but
                               // that does not affect us here anymore.
}
```

However, since I am not really iterating the iterator I could also just use `someRTree.begin()` in place of the iterator `it`. This is semantically identical. I just left it this way for convenience reasons.

Still, I wonder if there is a better solution. When removing elements from STL containers it's possible to get a iterator pointing to the element following the removed one. Something similar in boost could be advantageous. But there you can only return the number of elements which were removed.

Comment: "Something similar in boost could be advantageous" - but only if all other iterators stay valid. Really the way to generically address the issue is to keep a set of _removable entries_ and postpone the deletion till after the iteration. Of course, you might have to check whether nodes are already marked for deletion along the way.

Comment: Which other iterators do you mean? And thanks for the suggestion, but wouldn't this add unnecessary overhead and lead to less performance? In my case I have to deal with hundreds of thousands of 2D data point structures. Therefore it's beneficial if the tree shrinks during the iteration.

Comment: "other iterators" - all iterators referring to nodes other than the removed one (this is standard iterator invalidation behaviour for node-based containers like (std::list, std::[unordered_]{map,set}), and also other bespoke structures (like std::deque iff erased element is at either end))